# Error Missing { inserted

Tags: errors

```
\textbf{47.Consider the following relations:\\
\includegraphics[width=120mm]{Image6.png}\\
Consider the following SQL query.\\ 
SELECT S.Student$_$Name, sum (P.Marks)\\ 
FROM Student S,Performance P\\
WHERE S.Roll$_$No=P.Roll$_$No \\
GROUP BY S.Student$_$Name\\ 
The number of rows that will be returned by the SQL query is .........}\\
\vspace{2mm}\\
```

Error Missing { inserted....
Please help me out!

Answer (score 3):

`_` in math mode expects an argument to put into the subscript position. Use `\_` or `\textunderscore` instead of `$_$`:

```
SELECT S.Student\_Name
```

Or use verbatim:

```
\verb|S.Student_Name|
```

or package `listings` for code listings

or ...

### File ended while scanning use of `\textbf`

The closing `}` is missing in the line with `\textbf`. Corrected:

```
\textbf{47.Consider the following relations:}\\
```

Comment: ok thanks but then one more error came File ended while scanning use of \textbf .

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj I remember that I have upvoted a comment of Stephan Kottwitz to the question addressing this issue exactly. It seems, that the comment was deleted.